# set GitHub Actions input value for local testing

Tags: javascript, github-actions, building-github-actions

I'm writing a GitHub action that receives a mandatory input field named `file` using `@actions/core` library.

```js
const core = require("@actions/core");

async function run() {
    try {
        let file = core.getInput('file', {required: true});

        // rest of my action ...
```

I'm able to run it locally and it fails as expected as-is (no input provided).
**Is there a built-in way to provide inputs (similar to env-vars) so I could run and test it locally?**

```
Error: Input required and not supplied: file
    at Object.getInput (.../node_modules/@actions/core/lib/core.js:78:15)
    at run (.../src/main.js:6:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../src/main.js:40:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
::error::Input required and not supplied: file
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you look at [the sources of `getInput`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/c9819f79d2a27c1f26ef7ea85ff44346e7d60741/packages/core/src/core.ts#L69), you can see that it is using environment variables:

```
const val: string =
    process.env[`INPUT_${name.replace(/ /g, '_').toUpperCase()}`] || ''
```

Knowing this, you can just set this environment variable:

```js
const setInput = (name,value)=>
    process.env[`INPUT_${name.replace(/ /g, '_').toUpperCase()}`]=value;
```

Alternatively, you can also provide the environment variable from the parent process, e.g. `bash`:

```bash
export INPUT_YOUR_VARIABLE='whatever'
node main.js
```